# How many are there derivation rules in first order logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I have recently learned what are valid expressions in first order logic. Now I wonder what are "derivation rules" of first order logic. By a "derivation rule" I mean a rule that can take a first order logic expression and "generate" another expression that follow from it. Or, in a more general case, it take two expressions formulated with FOL syntax and generate a new (third) expression that follow from the original two expressions.

I guess that should be a known, well established list of those rules but for whatever reason I cannot find it. Can it be the case that I have some misconception?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rules_of_inference) will get you started.

Comment: See [Natural Deduction riles](https://iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4) for the basic ones.

Comment: You can used them to produce "derived rules, like e.g. $\dfrac {A \to B \ \ \ B \to C}{A \to C}$